# Firebase Auth Sign in With Google Not Working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have gone through almost all the  firebase google authentication questions on SO but still I am not able to find the solution to my issue.

Here is my code for Firebase Google Authentication

Inside **onCreate**

```
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                        }
                    })
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();

            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
```

**MethodToSignIn**

```
private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

**onActivityResult**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

**FirebaseAuthWithGoogle**

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("MainACtivity", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("Main", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("MainAcitivyt", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

**activity_welcome.xml**

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSendData"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

When I click on the Button I get the following in logcat and the app freezes

```
 D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
     V/FA: Using measurement service
     V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
     V/FA: Using measurement service
     V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
     V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 285185857
     D/FA: Connected to remote service
     V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 3
     V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
     V/FA: Connecting to remote service
     V/FA: Activity paused, time: 285382455
     D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=10085, _sc=SignInHubActivity, _si=3238861053606655861}]
     V/FA: Using measurement service
     V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
     D/FA: Connected to remote service
     V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
     V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

[image]

Comment: The logcat you posted is not an error, and they're actually Firebase Analytics logs. Please filter it to Error and then post the logcat again after the button click.
Have you tried [this official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) ?

Comment: Hi Wilik, I have checked the logcat and there isn't any error. Only getting the messages which I have posted.

Comment: are you sure about the device you are using? The case you mentioned generally happens in devices not having updated google play services.

Comment: @SaurabhPandey : also try to initialize mAuth first then Configure Google Sign In builder (GoogleSignInOptions gso = new Goog...)

Comment: I am using it on my mobile with updated google play services. Thanks for the suggestion I will try that.

Answer (score 2):

Specify your app's SHA-1 fingerprint from  your project settings in the 
    firebase console. Enable  google login in the sign-in method.Try the lastest dependencies also.